# error with integrating Jfreechart in Struts2

Tags: struts2, jfreechart, struts2-jfreechart-plugin

hello I'm trying to integrate jfreechart in struts 2 Aand i get a lot's of error messages

this is my struts

```
<package name="jfreechart" namespace="/" extends="jfreechart-default">
    <default-action-ref name="repporting" />
    <action name="repporting">
    <result>/web/userinterne/repporting.jsp</result>
    </action>
    <action name="Graphique" method="{1}" class="calendar.action.JfreeChartAction">
    <result name="success" type="chart">
    <param name="value">chart</param>
    <param name="type">png</param>
    <param name="width">600</param>
    <param name="height">400</param>
    </result>
    </action>
</package>
```

and this is my action

```
package calendar.action;


import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PiePlot3D;
import org.jfree.data.general.DefaultPieDataset;
import org.jfree.util.Rotation;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;


public class JfreeChartAction extends ActionSupport {

private JFreeChart chart;


public String execute() throws Exception {
DefaultPieDataset donnees=new DefaultPieDataset();
donnees.setValue("Code",05);
donnees.setValue("Développement",02);
donnees.setValue("Tests",06);
donnees.setValue("Maintenance",01);
chart = ChartFactory.createPieChart3D(
"Répartition du typologiecarte", //titre
donnees, // données à afficher
true, // afficher la légende
true,
true
);
// créer le camembert
PiePlot3D plot=(PiePlot3D) chart.getPlot();
// angle d’affichage
plot.setStartAngle(190);
// rotation
plot.setDirection(Rotation.CLOCKWISE);
// transparence du schéma
plot.setForegroundAlpha(0.4f);
plot.setNoDataMessage("Pas de données à afficher");
return SUCCESS;
}
// getter pour retourner l’image
public JFreeChart getChart() {
return chart;
}
}
```

and this is the jsp

```
 <body>
     <h3>Struts2-Jfreechart integration</h3>
     <br /> 

<img src="Graphique"/> 


</body>
```

whene i run the project i have this error

```
    SEVERE: Exception au démarrage du filtre struts2
Error building results for action Graphique in namespace / - action - file:/D:/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp3/wtpwebapps/SMP/WEB-INF/classes/config/pl/jfreechart.xml:13:101
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.addAction(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:340)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.addPackage(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:429)
    at org.apache.struts2.config.StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.loadPackages(StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.java:111)

    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:52)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:395)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:452)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.init(FilterDispatcher.java:201)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:275)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:397)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:3696)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4343)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:719)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:516)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:566)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:288)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413)
Caused by: There is no result type defined for type 'chart' mapped with name 'success' - result - file:/D:/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp3/wtpwebapps/SMP/WEB-INF/classes/config/pl/jfreechart.xml:14:39
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.buildResults(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:584)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.addAction(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:338)
    ... 27 more
```

I don't know how to resolve it can anybody help me please?

Comment: problem occurs due to wrong return type declaration.

Comment: make sure the result type is available to the configuration provider and you have updated versions of libraries.

Comment: i changed the type of declaration but it didn't work

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. The `method="{1}"` in the configuration and exception. And why your config file name is `jfreechart.xml`?

Comment: because i have many files of xml and they extend from struts file

Comment: @user3771706: Ok. What about `method="{1}"`?

Answer (score 0):

problem occurs due to wrong return type declaration

return String is `chart` but no result found this name.

```
    public String execute()  { return "success"; }
```

now try it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by adding a xwork-core-2.1.6.jar thanks to everyone makes effort to help me .

best regards